# file uploading either Image and either video files fetching and display condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["jpg/png"]) && !empty($_GET["jpg/png"])){?>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/images/<?php echo $blog_data->image; ?>" class="img-responsive" style="width:360px;height:270px;">

<?php } else { ?>

    <video width="300" height="200" controls>
    <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/images/<?php echo $blog_data->image; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<?php //} ?>
```

I expect images and videos want to be fetched at a time

Comment: is it your input name `jpg/png` ?? why this line commented `<?php //} ?>`?

Comment: jpg/png are my allowed types
<?php } ?> i forgeted to remove comment

Comment: how can i write condition for those images and videos can you please help me

Comment: from where you are getting `$_GET["jpg/png"]`

Comment: i were search code form google i just put it

Comment: send complete code